# how to call the spring controller method from form using java script or Jquery

Tags: java, javascript, spring-mvc

Hai i tried calling the controller using

```
document.forms[0].value = "getSignFaces";

document.forms[0].submit();
```

But its not calling method in controller

```
@RequestMapping(value=signFaces.do, method=RequestMethod.POST , params ="getSignFaces")

    public String getSignFaces(Model model,@ModelAttribute(HBMSWebConstants.MODEL_SIGN_DETAILS) HBMSSessionDataWO sessionData,
@ModelAttribute SignDetailsForm form,HttpServletRequest request, 
HttpServletResponse response,@RequestParam String noOfFaces,
```

I need to send the noOfFaces to this method.

Some how it is failling. Please let me know if i am missing any thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try using an ajax call to do the post to the controller.

as an example:

```
var jsonfile= {json:JSON.stringify(contents)};
$.ajax({
type:'POST',
url: "/yourcontrollermapping/signFaces.do
data: jsonfile,
dataType: "json"
});
```

and then your controller method:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/yourcontrollermapping"
public class YourController(){
@RequestMapping(value = "/signFaces.do, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void getSignFaces(@RequestParam("json) String json){
//stuff you want to do
}
}
```

If you wanne do it javascript native you can :

```
var jsonfile= {json:JSON.stringify(contents)};
var r = new XMLHttpRequest(); r.open("POST", "yourcontrollermapping/signFaces.do", true); r.onreadystatechange = function () {  if (r.readyState != 4 || r.status != 200) return;   console.log(r.responseText); }; r.send(jsonFile);
```

Comment: Could the controller method be called from a non-ajax/plain JS function?

Comment: @Clay Banks I updated my answer to accommodate your question.